# Как получить минимальное число массива (цена $arPrice['PRICE'])

Tags: php, min

```
$ar1=Array(); 
$ar2=Array();

$arArtPrices = array_merge($ar1,$ar2); 
foreach($arArtPrices as $arPrice){ 

    $minprice = array($arPrice['PRICE']) 
    var_dump($minprice)

    if ($arPrice['PRICE'] == $minprice) { 

    }
}
```

Нужно получить минимальную цену товара...

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "388.64" } array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "390.62" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "395.23" } array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "491.11" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "500.94" } array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "501.60" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "508.42" } array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "610.64" } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "671.00" } array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "877.06" }
```

Comment: да минимальное число в массиве...

Comment: Тогда просто после `array_merge()` можно использовать [`min`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.min.php)

Comment: не получиться (  нужна именно цена она в $arPrice['PRICE']... в массиве $ar2 куча всего...

Comment: `min(array_column(array_merge($ar, $ar2), 'price'))`, однако, не ясно вообще зачем там два массива и что в них содержится

Comment: вы товарищ ищите с минимальной ценой, или саму цену? Если только цену, то зачем вообще что-либо сранивать. Если первый товар с минимальной ценой, то сделайте в этом ифе брейк и завершите цикл